# Azure Devops Analytics Work Item Query with Team Id

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019

Is it possible to query the _odata end point for work items and get the actual team id that the work items are assigned to? I can expand the Teams navigation property but that just gives me a list of all project teams, not the team that the work item belongs to

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization_name}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?select=WorkItemId,Title,WorkItemType
```

Comment: Hi @Matthew The Terrible, How are things going? Have you tried like as the example I shared in the answer? Is it helpful to you? Please try it, and any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can expand the Teams navigation property but that just gives me a list of all project teams, not the team that the work item belongs to

What is the full URL of the OData you are using?

The OData URL you shared seems is not the full.

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization_name}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?select=WorkItemId,Title,WorkItemType
```

I also try expand the teams in the query and it can correctly display the teams which the work items are owned by.

The following is the full URL of the OData I test on Postman:

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?$select=WorkItemId, WorkItemType, Title, State, TagNames&$expand=AssignedTo($select=UserEmail), Area($select=AreaPath), Iteration($select=IterationPath), Teams($select=TeamName)&$filter=(Area/AreaPath eq '{AreaPath}')
```

Result:
[image]

If the area path of the work item has been assigned to multiple teams, in the **`Teams`** object, it will list all the teams which the area path is assigned to.
[image]